# Double-tap or two single-taps?

Tags: iphone

What is the time limit for two taps to be considered a double-tap, on the iPhone OS?

// Edit: Why is this important?

In order to handle single-tap and double-tap differently, Apple's guide says to do `performSelector...afterDelay` with some 'reasonable' interval on first tap (and cancel it later if the second tap is detected).

The problem is that if the interval is too short (0.1), the single tap action will be performed even when double-tapping (if relying only on tapCount, that is). If it's too long (0.8), the user will be waiting unnecessarily for the single-tap to be recognized, when there is no possibility for a double-tap.

It has to be *exactly* the correct number, in order to work optimally, but definitely not smaller, or there's a chance for bugs (simultaneous single-tap and double-tap).

Comment: You may want to specify what platform you are asking about.

Comment: @retracile : there is an "iphone" tag on this question (well, maybe it wasn't there 35 seconds ago, when you posted your comment) ; so, I'm guessing it's on an iphone-platform ;-)

Comment: The post hasn't been edited yet, it appears.

Comment: guess I missed it, sorry

Comment: Perfect question and well posed, I've been facing the same problem! After several tests looks like the exact time delay is **0.5 seconds**! This is an eternity, and it slows down even the execution of a simple tap, giving a sluggish impression to your interface.
We need customization of the tapcount time delay!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can detect any number of tap by the tap gesture. No need of playing with `NSTouches` either. For all the user seeking for the solution here it is.

***These simple lines of code does the duty of single and double tap functionality.***

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecg = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                             initWithTarget:self 
                                             action:@selector(doubleTapped:)];
    doubleTapRecg.delegate = self;
    doubleTapRecg.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTapRecg.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecg];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecg = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self 
                                       action:@selector(tapped:)];
    tapRecg.delegate = self;
    tapRecg.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapRecg.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecg];
    [tapRecg requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecg];


    [doubleTapRecg release];
    [tapRecg release];
```

Comment: I'm changing the accepted answer to this, since it seems the proper way to do it nowadays. But before commenting the previous answer and calling other answers rubbish, keep in mind they were posted 3 years before yours and before UITapGestureRecognizer even existed ;)

Comment: that was my other account :D

Comment: Without manual timers or delays that force you to decide how many msecs to wait, awesome!

Answer (score 10):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    NSUInteger tapCount = [touch tapCount];

    switch (tapCount) {
        case 1:
            [self performSelector:@selector(singleTapMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:.4];
            break;
        case 2:
            [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(singleTapMethod) object:nil];
            [self performSelector:@selector(doubleTapMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:.4];
            break;
        case 3:
            [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doubleTapMethod) object:nil];
            [self performSelector:@selector(tripleTapMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:.4];
            break;
        case 4:
            [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(tripleTapMethod) object:nil];
            [self quadrupleTap];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
@end
```

for me this code is working prefectly fine.... :) the last post was around august 15 09....
but i was going through the same problem so thought to share the solution i found....

Answer (score 8):

In the Apple provided example of the [iPhone Application Programming Guide: Event Handling](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/EventHandling/EventHandling.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9) (mentioned by user Italy) a delay of `0.3` is used:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(handleSingleTap:) withObject:touchLoc afterDelay:0.3];
```

Answer (score 5):

On Developer Forums on developer.apple.com, an Apple developer said:

- There's no constant time interval, but the system-wide definition is implicit today in the tapCount property of UITouch.
- There is not default value for this delay and for touch-and-hold delay.
- SpringBoard has the value hardcoded.

I have submitted this to Apple as [bug 68405](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=68405).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a default time-limit - it's whatever "feels" right when you try it out. Apple has an example [here](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/EventHandling/EventHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9), where they don't specify a specific time either.

Comment: There must be a limit, since UITouch's tapCount doesn't increase if the clicks are a second apart, yet it does if they are close together.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing things but this code is working well for me.

in my .h file:

```
 @interface MyViewController : UIViewController { 

 int tapCount; 

 } 
 @property (nonatomic, assign)int tapCount; 
 @end
```

in my .m file:

```
@synthesize tapCount;

- (void)tapGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture {
    tapCount = tapCount + 1;
    [self performSelector:@selector(correctTapCount) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];


}
-(void)correctTapCount {
    if (tapCount == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Single Tap");
    }
    if (tapCount == 2) {
        NSLog(@"Double Tap");
    }

    //reset TapCount
    tapCount = 0;
}
```

And this is where I add my tap listener (it is on a UIImageView )

```
//add tap listener
carImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
[carImage addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[tap release];
```

Good Luck and Happy Coding!