# Double tapping problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im working on an app with zooming function.
In this app I have this button. I want it to respond to tapping in several ways:

Single tap: Zoom in slightly.

Double tap: Zoom in to the max.

Ive tried several options to achieve this but none are what I want.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

---

```
[zoomin addTarget:self action:@selector(zoominMax) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];
```

Both work on single and double tap but when I press the button once to slightly zoom and seconds later I press it again it doesn't zoom in slightly, it zooms in to the max.

It is possible to fix this with a timer and location check so that when u tap and tap again u can be sure that the location is in a similar area and the taps happened within timer range.

But is this what I really need? 
Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with two gesture recognizers and a timer:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)] autorelease];
[myView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGestureRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)] autorelease];
doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[myView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGestureRecognizer];
```

You'll have to use a slight delay in your `tap:` action before zooming in slightly because the first tap could be followed by a second tap:

```
- (void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(singleTap) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];
}

- (void)singleTap
{
    //slightly zoom in...
}

- (void)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    //Cancel the timer for the single tap action:
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(singleTap) object:nil];
    //zoom in to the max zoom level...
}
```

Comment: I understand you are trying to prevent the first tap in a double tap to be recognized as a single tap. This can be achieved with the `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` build-in method instead of a custom timer. Anyway, I don't think this is the issue here. The OP is complaining that a single tap seconds after another single tap is resulting in an unwanted double tap: "when I press the button once to slightly zoom and seconds later I press it again it doesn't zoom in slightly, it zooms in to the max."

Comment: This is kinda what i expected it to be.
It sure is clean and simple.
Thanks.

Comment: @albertamg Good point, hadn't thought of that. The timer method does have one advantage though: You can customize the time that is allowed to pass between two taps for them to be recognized as a double-tap. If I remember correctly, `UITapRecognizer` does allow a fairly long interval between taps so that single taps are recognized later than you might want.

Comment: @omz bear in mind that the time interval that `UITapRecognizer` allows between taps is the one that counts when deciding what is a double tap. If you configure a shorter time interval in your custom timer, your `singleTap` method could run before your `doubleTap:` action method is called. So, the minimum safe time interval is the amount of time that `UITapRecognizer` allows between taps, not less.

Comment: @albertamg Hmm, you're right. In this specific case it might still be desirable to recognize a single tap earlier than when the double-tap recognizer fails because the actions (zooming in a little and zooming in completely) don't contradict each other. Otherwise it would be more likely that users accidentally double-tap, thinking that the first tap wasn't recognized at all.

Comment: @omz so you are proposing a mixed approach where a speedy double tap doesn't get a single tap but a slowish double tap gets a single tap first?

Comment: @albertamg Right, though I have to admit that I wasn't fully aware of this implication before you pointed it out.

Comment: @omz Alright :) It was nice talking to you. Let's leave it at that before the "move to chat" alert comes up ;-)

Answer (score 5):

the solution provided by omz is not good.

where as you can do this by simply adding these lines of code like posted here. [Double-tap or two single-taps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282504/double-tap-or-two-single-taps/12397367#12397367)

***NOTE THE MAGICAL LINE :*** `[tapRecg requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecg];`

***ABSTRACT:***

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecg = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                             initWithTarget:self 
                                             action:@selector(doubleTapped:)];
    doubleTapRecg.delegate = self;
    doubleTapRecg.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTapRecg.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecg];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecg = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self 
                                       action:@selector(tapped:)];
    tapRecg.delegate = self;
    tapRecg.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapRecg.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecg];
    [tapRecg requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecg];


    [doubleTapRecg release];
    [tapRecg release];
```

Comment: @yunas Great answer, thanks. One minor point: setting the delegates on the recognizers is optional here and doesn't affect the outcome.